# Using form to filter search results

Tags: html, forms

I have a client asking for a page similar to this - http://www.candlelighthomes.com/homedesigns.php - where you can use the search form to filter out what type of results you're seeing in the home plans. I've never done anything like that before, and honestly am not sure where to start. Can anyone tell me what type of coding is used to do it - is it just javascript, or is it PHP? I've tried googling it but am not really sure how to phrase what I'm looking for. I also looked at the page source but couldn't tell entirely what was making it work.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP and SQL to only fetch data matching the criteria from the Database.

In the end your query should look something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM properties WHERE price BETWEEN $minPrice AND $maxPrice";
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll want to look into Ajax, PHP, and Javascript to solve this problem. You can use PHP to manipulate and format the data you want to display (PHP is a server-side scripting language). Ajax is used to communicate and send data between javascript and php scripts, so you can use that to grab your data. Finally, write a javascript to put your data where it needs to be in your webpage.

I know that sounds complicated, but to accomplish this you'll need to have at least a basic understanding of how JavaScript, Ajax (Search for Ajax with JQuery) and PHP. I learned by using examples from W3 Schools. Here's some helpful links to get you started.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp